# More Elegant Solution To Fetching a Selector From Within Two IFrames

Tags: javascript, promise, puppeteer

I've been working on a webscraper that uses puppeteer. The scraper, as shown below, aims to click on a button that is inside of **two iframes**, although the website that I'm working with generates the content of the iframes with a bunch of javascript and it can take upwards of 8 seconds for the button to render(during which there are also a number of open connections between server and client, so `page.waitForNetworkIdle()` is out of the question). The code here actually works; however, I'm sure of the existence of some significantly more elegant solution to this problem, most likely not involving async functions. I tried using a couple of promise-chaining patterns earlier but nothing seemed to work. If anyone could point me to some method for solving this problem with less jank, I'd be grateful.

```js
  const t = 5000;
  function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
  //--------------------------------------------------//
  var tFrame = await page.waitForFrame(async fr => {
    return fr.name().length === 5
  })
  var ebRealModal = tFrame.childFrames().find(fra => {return fra.name() === 'ebRealModal'}); 
   var search = null
   while(search === null || search === undefined){
   tFrame = page.frames().find(fra => {return fra.name().length === 5});
   if(tFrame !== null && tFrame !== undefined){
   ebRealModal = tFrame.childFrames().find(fra => {return fra.name() === 'ebRealModal'});
   if(ebRealModal !== null && ebRealModal !== undefined){
     search = await ebRealModal.$("#search")
   }
  }
   await delay(t)
  }
  button = await ebRealModal.$("#search");
  await button.evaluate(b => b.click());
```

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the site, but often you can just navigate to the iframe src. Or just grab the iframe by selector and dip into its content document if you want to stay on the parent page. Minor, but you don't need to reimplent `delay`, it's `page.waitForTimeout` already.

Comment: Also, I suggest putting your code through [prettier](https://prettier.io/playground) using `const`/`let` instead of `var`, always using any of those instead of creating a global with `button  =`, skipping `{}`s and `return` on single-expression arrow funcs and using `for` instead of `while` loops. All of this will result in less jank and more elegance. Re: `waitForNetworkIdle` you can use `waitForResponse` for blocking on a specific endpoint repsonse.

Comment: There won't be a non-async solution in Puppeteer. The whole API is async because it deals with slow connections to the browser. There's no reason to freeze the Node thread as it sits idle waiting to hear back from the browser.

Comment: Thank you for all of the feedback @ggorlen , although, just to clarify, I was asking if there was a nice way to do this without *async functions* not without any asynchronicity, I'm just assuming that there's some way to do it with pure promises. Also, page.waitForTimeout was deprecated a few months ago.

Comment: Fantastic news re: `waitForTimeout`, thanks. It's poor practice in any form. I'm not sure what you mean by pure promises... are you referring to `.then`? That's the only other option than `async`/`await` but I'm not sure if it's any more or less "pure", and `.then` is typically awkward with Puppeteer.